Cómo mostrar en imagen archivos TTF y OTF
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que consiste en generar una imagen a partir de archivos de fuentes TTF y OTF que se cargan desde un input en una página web. Mi objetivo es lograr una visualización del archivo tipográfico que sea similar a lo que se ofrece en fontiko.com. La idea es que los usuarios puedan seleccionar una fuente desde su dispositivo y que, de manera dinámica, se muestre en el navegador en un formato visual atractivo.
Este es mi avance hasta el momento: he implementado un sistema básico que permite cargar el archivo de fuente y renderizarlo en un canvas HTML, donde se dibuja un texto predeterminado utilizando la fuente seleccionada. Estoy buscando mejorar la interacción y la presentación, asegurándome de que la experiencia sea fluida y amigable para el usuario.


document.getElementById('fontInput').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const fontInfo = document.getElementById('fontInfo');

    // Verifica que se haya seleccionado un archivo válido
    if (file && (file.type === 'font/ttf' || file.type === 'font/otf' || file.name.endsWith('.ttf') || file.name.endsWith('.otf'))) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            // Crea un nuevo objeto FontFace con los datos leídos
            const font = new FontFace('uploadedFont', e.target.result);

            font.load().then(function(loadedFont) {
                // Agrega la fuente a la colección de fuentes del documento
                document.fonts.add(loadedFont);

                // Dibuja el texto en el canvas usando la nueva fuente
                drawTextWithFont('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 'uploadedFont');

                // Muestra información sobre la fuente cargada
                fontInfo.textContent = `Loaded font: ${file.name}`;
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error('Error loading font:', error);
                fontInfo.textContent = 'Error loading font. Please try again.';
            });
        };

        // Lee el archivo como un ArrayBuffer
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    } else {
        alert('Please select a valid TTF or OTF font file.');
        fontInfo.textContent = 'Invalid file selected. Please choose a TTF or OTF font file.';
    }
});

function drawTextWithFont(text, fontName) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('fontCanvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Limpia el canvas antes de dibujar
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Configura el estilo del texto
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.font = `48px ${fontName}`;

    // Dibuja el texto en el canvas
    context.fillText(text, 50, 100);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- Define el conjunto de caracteres utilizado -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- Para responsividad en dispositivos móviles -->
    <title>Font Viewer</title> <!-- Título de la página -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> <!-- Vincula el archivo CSS para estilos -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Font Viewer</h1> <!-- Título principal de la página -->
    
    <!-- Input para seleccionar archivos, acepta solo archivos TTF y OTF -->
    <input type="file" id="fontInput" accept=".ttf, .otf">
    
    <!-- Canvas donde se dibujará el texto utilizando la fuente seleccionada -->
    <canvas id="fontCanvas" width="800" height="200"></canvas>
    
    <!-- Elemento para mostrar información sobre la fuente cargada -->
    <p id="fontInfo"></p>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script> <!-- Vincula el archivo JavaScript -->
</body>
</html>




Bienvenido. Cuál es la pregunta?
